# Select range of date in Calendar OR Slider using JAVA swing

Tags: java, swing, date, datepicker, datetimepicker

I am very new to java and I have been assigned a task in which I have to select single date (01-01-2011) or range of dates like (from 01-01-2011 to 22-03-2011)along with time, Time can also be optionally selected.

I was previously a web developer and there are a lot of date or time range picker available there and they are very easy to customize. But in JAVA, everything seems complex.

I have seen some examples on internet so far like [LGoodDatePicker](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker) BUT I don't have any idea how to implement this.
Any tutorial or straight guideline will help me alot.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LGoodDatePicker is great, I am also using it. I would suggest you to stick to, what is widely used to get help.

LGoodDatePicker has [demo code](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker/tree/master/Project/src/main/java/com/github/lgooddatepicker/demo) in GitHub repo. I used those example codes to figure out how to implement it. You can compare those to the screenshots provided [here](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker).

Generally, you can create a component with something like this:

```
DatePickerSettings datePickerSettings = new DatePickerSettings();
datePickerSettings.setFormatForDatesBeforeCommonEra("dd.MM.yyyy");
datePickerSettings.setFormatForDatesCommonEra("dd.MM.yyyy");
TimePickerSettings timePickerSettings = new TimePickerSettings();
timePickerSettings.use24HourClockFormat();

DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(datePickerSettings);
panel.add(datePicker);
datePicker.setDateToToday();
```

A range is nothing but a **start** and **end date**. You could **use 2 such components** for a start date and an end date. You need to check that start date is **before** end date.

Comment: That's very good, I will look into it. And will come back If I found my solution

Comment: How can I disable dates from given range. Lets say I have a range from 01-01-2011 to 01-01-2013, before and after these dates, all the dates should be disable. Any Idea ?

Comment: I have never tried it but they refer to this with a non-intuitive name: veto policy. I guess setting a veto policy might prevents certain dates to be selected: https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker/blob/master/Project/src/main/java/com/github/lgooddatepicker/optionalusertools/DateVetoPolicy.java